# Call method in ViewDidLoad()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, self

I'm calling a method on a key event which updates a label.

```
    [self updateFolderText];
```

When I do this in the event method it works, but when I try to do this in the ViewDidLoad() I get a compiler error.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];     
    [self updateFolderText];
}
```

I get the following error:

```
    error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Receiver type 'ViewController' 
for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'updateFolderText'
```

Ehm... I guess this must be trivial... I'm new to objective-c. Thanks. :)

Comment: What happened if you inversed the instructions ? (call `[self updateFolderText];` then `[super viewDidLoad]; `)

Comment: Is that method delcared in the .h of your view controller then implemented in your .m? What I'm asking really is... where is this method located?  I would do what Zakaria said... Lol.

Comment: haha... damn it... I really forgot to put it into the header file. I'm sorry, it was a very long day ;)

Comment: Is your key event exposed by the same viewcontroller with the `viewDidLoad`?  Is this a compiler error or runtime error (did you encounter the error while compiling or running the program)?  I realize you said compiler in the Q, but I want to make sure.  Also, is this a warning or an error if its showing up during compile time?  If its a warning, then the answer is to either define the `updateFolderText` method above your `viewDidLoad` or explicitly declare it in your interface (.h) file or in a class continuation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is probably because your method `updateFolderText` is defined below `viewDidLoad`. Move your code for `updateFolderText` below, and it should work.

Or, you can declare the method explicitly in your class. Add the following above `@implementation`.

```
@interface className()
-(void)yourMethod; //not sure how youve fully define updateFolderText
@end
```

or, as you say, you can also define it in your header file:

```
-(void)yourMethod; //not sure how youve fully define updateFolderText
```

Comment: three answers all the same - now there's some decent answer validation ;-)

Comment: You don't have to explicitly declare methods in order to call them.  This is why its possible to call private api's.  Objective C doesn't have "private" methods - just hidden ones.  I think his problem is more likely that `self` doesn't respond to that selector for some reason.  It would be easier to tell if we could see more code.

Comment: @Gaz_Edge, Yap, it worked for the second one because the method was declare above it but not for the first one (in ViewDidLoad()) because the method was below it. I forgot to put it into the header file...

Comment: Looks like he had a compiler warning, not an error based off his comment, so your solution does indeed solve his issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have declared the function updateFolderText in the .h of teh viewcontroller before the @end usually (for public functions) or for private functions you would declare it at the top of the .m with

```
@interface viewcontrollername()
-(void)updateFolderText;
@end
```

it was probably working else where in code because you have the function itself above where it gets called

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your method is declared in the interface for your class. There are two options for this. To declare it as a publicly accessible method for your class, you must put it in the header (.h) file.

The declaration would look something like:

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController
- (void)updateFolderText;
@end
```

To declare is as a method that is only accessible within your class (well, not really, but effectively) then you can put this at the top of your .m file, before @implementation

```
@interface myClass ()
- (void)updateFolderText;
@end
```

This second approach makes the method "private" as far as build time warnings are concerned. Note that actually the class will still respond to this selector at runtime though.

Comment: Second way of doing it is called a "Class Continuation" and they're awesome.  :D  As you say, not private but hidden so effectively private.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `-(void)updateFolderText` is defined, either in your .h file or in your private interface in the .m file. Also, if `-(void)updateFolderText` is physically located ABOVE the viewDidLoad method in your .m file, it should be able to see it ok.